# Change column name in pivot_wider for Boolean column

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr

I have some data that I want to `pivot_wider`, using one or more `names_from` columns. At least one of the potential `names_from` columns is Boolean.

This results in uninformative default column names like `TRUE`, `FALSE` or `TRUE_somevalue`, `FALSE_somevalue` (where `somevalue` is an otherwise meaningful level from another column).

I would like to instead use some more informative column name when some `names_from` column or columns are Boolean, for instance, `varnameTRUE`, `varnameFALSE` or `varnameTRUE_somevalue`, `varnameFALSE_somevalue` (where `varname` is the name of the Boolean column in the first place).

Obviously, I could convert the Boolean column to character or factor with meaningful names in the first place, but I'm wondering if there's some generalizable way to do this using the arguments available to `pivot_wider`. I can't figure out a way to do it with e.g. `names_glue` or `names_sep`. Ideally I'd like to be able to do this without even manually specifying the relevant columns, but have it happen automatically if a `names_from` column is a Boolean one.

Is there some way to do this?

Some example data:

```
test_dat <- tibble(
  idx = c(rep("a", 6), rep("b", 6)), 
  boo = c(rep(c(TRUE, FALSE), 6)), 
  word = c(rep(c("foo", "bar", "baz"), 4)), 
  val = runif(12)
)

> test_dat
# A tibble: 12 × 4
   idx   boo   word     val
   <chr> <lgl> <chr>  <dbl>
 1 a     TRUE  foo   0.325 
 2 a     FALSE bar   0.770 
 3 a     TRUE  baz   0.824 
 4 a     FALSE foo   0.351 
 5 a     TRUE  bar   0.555 
 6 a     FALSE baz   0.698 
 7 b     TRUE  foo   0.0200
 8 b     FALSE bar   0.427 
 9 b     TRUE  baz   0.325 
10 b     FALSE foo   0.463 
11 b     TRUE  bar   0.987 
12 b     FALSE baz   0.345
```

Default output:

```
> test_dat %>% pivot_wider(names_from=c("boo", "word"), values_from=val)
# A tibble: 2 × 7
  idx   TRUE_foo FALSE_bar TRUE_baz FALSE_foo TRUE_bar FALSE_baz
  <chr>    <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
1 a       0.325      0.770    0.824     0.351    0.555     0.698
2 b       0.0200     0.427    0.325     0.463    0.987     0.345
```

Desired output would be identical except with column names more like `booTRUE_foo`, `booFALSE_foo` (or some variant thereof, e.g. `boo_foo`, `notboo_foo`)

Comment: How about just using `name_prefix="boo"`?

Comment: That would work in a single instance but I'm ideally looking for a more generalizable / automatic solution. In my actual data / workflow there are many repeated `pivot_wider` calls on different combinations of columns including multiple potential Boolean columns. Most of it can be easily handled in a loop as needed but not sure how to deal with this part. Specifying `name_prefix="boo"` would require manual specification every time it comes up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can append column names to those boolean(logical) columns at first with `dplyr` functions:

```
mutate(across(where(is.logical), ...))
```

before pivoting to wide. By this way you don't need to require manual specification of the boolean column names.

```r
library(tidyverse)

test_dat %>%
  mutate(across(where(is.logical), ~ paste0(cur_column(), .x))) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = c(boo, word), values_from = val)

# # A tibble: 2 × 7
#   idx   booTRUE_foo booFALSE_bar booTRUE_baz booFALSE_foo booTRUE_bar booFALSE_baz
#   <chr>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>
# 1 a          0.0556        0.679      0.409         0.666       0.675        0.312
# 2 b          0.281         0.477      0.0817        0.977       0.745        0.340
```

Comment: I like this - compact, general, and automatic. Still think it's odd that you can't do it in `pivot_wider` by default but this is the next best option!